# Set custom probability threshold for Keras CNN

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

Surprised I can't quickly find this info online--

After training my CNN I grabbed the predictions by running;

predictions = model.predict_generator(test_generator, steps=num_test)

Rather than use 
predicted_classes = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)

I'd like to set a threshold of anything greater than 0.3 probability being labeled as class 1, rather than 0.5. Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

Comment: Is this binary classification?

Comment: yes binary classification

Answer (score 0):

If it is a binary classification you could try:

```
i=0    
while i < len(predictions):
   if(predictions[a]<=0.3):
    predictions[a]=0
   else:
    predictions[a]=0
   i+=1
```

This should "round" to class 1 if the predicted value is bigger than 0.3

Answer (score 0):

There is no place in Keras to set such threshold, even as Keras uses 0.5 to compute the `binary_accuracy` metric. Your only option is to manually threshold the predictions:

```
 predictions = model.predict_generator(test_generator, steps=num_test)
 classes = predictions > 0.3
```